# System.Reactive - Combining 2 observables into a stream with all permutations

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm looking to combine 2 observable sequences with a selector function that would push a result for each possible combination between elements of the two sequences:

```
  var o1 = new Subject<string>();
  var o2 = new Subject<string>();

  IObservable<string> result = o1.CreatePermutations(o2, (item1, item2) => $"{item1}{item2}");
```

Expected result should be:

```
  o1.OnNext("A"); // nothing happens
  o2.OnNext("1");  // result pushes: "A1"
  o1.OnNext("B");  // result pushes: "B1"
  o2.OnNext("2");   // result pushes: "A2", "B2"
  o1.OnNext("C");  // result pushes: "C1", "C2"
```

How could such a CreatePermutations function be implemented?

All combinatory operators I can think of (CombineLatest, Zip etc) only seem to work with the latest values being pushed in each stream and don't preserve/combine the full history (Replay) of each stream when needed - so can't really think of a good way to approach this at the moment

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straight-forward `Join` problem:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> CreatePermutations<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TLeft> o1, 
    IObservable<TRight> o2, 
    Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> selector
)
{
    return o1.Join(o2, 
        _ => Observable.Never<Unit>(), 
        _ => Observable.Never<Unit>(), 
        selector
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work

```
public static IObservable<string> CreatePermutations(this IObservable<string> source, 
                                                     IObservable<string> other)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(obs =>
    {
        var or = other.Replay();
        var sequence = source.SelectMany(i => or.Select(j => $"{i}{j}"));                             

        return new CompositeDisposable(new [] { sequence.Subscribe(obs),
                                                or.Connect()
                                              });
    });
}
```

Comment: Very good. Nice query. I'd just swap the `or.Connect()` and `sequence.Subscribe(obs)` to avoid a possible race condition.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks but can you elaborate: isn't there a similar condition if we swap them?

Comment: Well, the way I read it the `sequence` can't produce values until both `source` and `or` do. So it's possible that if `or` is started before `sequence` then you might miss values. I don't think, in this case, that it can happen the other way.